# How to run TYPO3 functional tests with ddev?

Tags: phpunit, typo3, functional-testing, ddev

I tried running functional tests for a TYPO3 extension inside ddev. I ran into the issue, that TYPO3 tries to create new databases for the tests but the default ddev db user named `db` is not allowed to create new databases.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The "TYPO3 explained" core documentation recently added a chapter about testing. It gives some insight on how extension and project testing can be done: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Testing/Index.html.

For extensions, an own containerized test system is started for functional tests, for projects an example using ddev to execute acceptance tests is documented. The latter one might be changed / extended for functional tests. The testing docs also explain why TYPO3 creates own instances per test.

Answer (score 1):

The ddev database container also provides a root user you can use for this.
Just use `root` as username and also `root` as password for your tests.